# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError when using playSound() in a Minecraft plugin

Tags: minecraft

So I have been tweaking this older plugin (called RandomSpawn) due to some bugs that I have noticed with chunk loading. Everything works perfectly except for when I call playSound(), which throws a Java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ENDERMAN_TELEPORT. What I want to know is why it throws this error/how to fix it.

Here is the code: `target.playSound(target.getLocation(), Sound.ENDERMAN_TELEPORT, 3f, 1f);` where target is the player.

Comment: What version of the bukkit API are you targeting, and what version is the server running? (do `/version`)

Comment: 1. The complete error message
2. A bit more code pls
:)

Answer (score 1):

The most likely problem is that you are using a different version of the bukkit API then your server is running on.

For versions 1.9 and above the sound you are looking for is called `ENTITY_ENDERMEN_TELEPORT`. The name you are using is for older versions.